Shopify inventory_levels set API returns not found error. All other APIs working correctly
We have a stock and price update service, which is trying to update the stock of an item through API. But, it fails with a message "Not Found".
The same service was working fine with a test account. Price and stock were updating correctly. When we switched credentials to the actual site, only the price update worked and the stock update failed with "Not Found" message.
This happens every time. It happens even if I try the same request from Postman or curl.
We tried with API versions 2024-04 and 2023-07.
It is happening only via the API. We can directly update the stock by logging in to the shopify admin console.
Please find the below request details to get the currenct inventory level which is working correctly.
Request GET
/admin/api/2024-04/inventory_levels.json?inventory_item_ids=51191952113953
Response
{
    "inventory_levels": [
        {
            "inventory_item_id": 51191952113953,
            "location_id": 76281872673,
            "available": 2,
            "updated_at": "2024-06-04T11:52:50+03:00",
            "admin_graphql_api_id": "gid://shopify/InventoryLevel/112663920929?inventory_item_id=51191952113953"
        }
    ]
}

Please find the below request where it failed to update the inventory level
Request POST
/admin/api/2024-04/inventory_levels/set.json
{
   "inventory_item_id": 51191952113953,
    "location_id": 76281872673,
    "available": 3
}

Response
{
    "errors": "Not Found"
}

